# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException on output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to display an image on jsp from local drive. 
I set the img src as `src = "../../../ImageServlet"` in jsp but I am getting a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException 
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.ServletResponseWrapperInclude.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapperInclude.java:63) 
    at DisplayImageServlet.doPost(ImageServlet.java:95)
    at DisplayImageServlet.doGet(ImageServlet.java:34)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

exception.

My Servlet Code is:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)    throws   ServletException, IOException {
String applicationNumber = (String)session.getAttribute("APPLICATIONNUMBER");
File file = new File("C:/photos/"+applicationNumber+".jpg");

        response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
            if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and my jsp img tag is like-

```
<div>
                <div>
                  <label>Photo </label>
                  <div>
                    <div style="width:194px;height:162px;"><img src="../../../ImageServlet" id="Image" style="width:100px;height:100px;" /></div>
                    <div style="margin-left:115px; margin-top:10px;">
                      <input  name="filename" type="file" id="filename"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Please help me out or is there any other way to do the same.
Thanks.

Comment: I think `response.getOutputStream()` throws the exception, rather than `new BufferedOutputStream(...)`. Probably the response isn't writable yet.

Comment: I have already checked the response and it is not committed. response.isCommitted() is returning as false.

Comment: Do you have any filters configured? If so, do these use response.getWriter() ? You can only do EITHER response.getWriter() OR response.getOutputStream().

Comment: It is not allowed to call that in **INCLUDE** dispatch. Not sure why they have this limitation... https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/jasper/runtime/ServletResponseWrapperInclude.java#L65

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user3035077 try the following code..

```
try {
      HttpSession session=request.getSession();
      String applicationNumber = (String)session.getAttribute("APPREFNUMBER");
      File file = new File("C:/photos/"+applicationNumber+".jpg");
      if (file.exists()) {
         BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                                new FileInputStream(file));

         // Get image contents.
        byte[] bytes = new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(bytes);
        in.close();
         // Write image contents to response.
        response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
          }
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: You are welcome, Mark this as answer, so others will get benefit from this answer.